# Ran into a problem running Bpython

Tags: linux-mint, python

I used the `sudo apt-get install bpython` command to install bpython. Now when I type `bpython`, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/bpython", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: bpython==0.12
```

Comment: Did you report the problem to the maintainers of your distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is uninstall from the package `sudo apt-get remove bpython` and install via pip: `sudo pip install bpython`.

I think what's going on is that the bpython package assumes python 2.7 in `/usr/bin/python`, but from the traceback, your `/usr/bin/python` seems to be python3.

To verify try running `/usr/bin/python -V` to see the version and compare with the output of `dpkg -L bpython` where you might see stuff like: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bpython/args.py`

If that all is the case then, yes, you may also want to report this to the distribution maintainers so they can fix the package.